# Jtable with Different Structure

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, rounded-corners

I have jTable with default(Rectangular or square) structure.I want to make corner of the jTable rounder.

Is there any method or way available for that?

I have already checked the [JTable API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) but i didn't find any thing useable.

For a reference I have attached this image.

[image]

**Description of the image -**

I want to make highlighted areas rounder.

Comment: Refer this http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/03/18/translucent-and-shaped-swing-windows.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class JtableExample {

     public static void main(String args[]) {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            Object rowData[][] = { { "Row1-Column1", "Row1-Column2", "Row1-Column3" },
                { "Row2-Column1", "Row2-Column2", "Row2-Column3" } };
            Object columnNames[] = { "Column One", "Column Two", "Column Three" };
            JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);

            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
            frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            Border roundedBorder = new LineBorder(Color.black, 5, true); // the third parameter - true, says it's round
            scrollPane.setBorder(roundedBorder);
            frame.setSize(300, 150);
            frame.setVisible(true);

          }


}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.Can we do the same without using border.

Answer (score 1):

Searching the JTable APIs for the look and feel is the wrong place to search. The JTable class is concerned with the implementation of the table related properties. [`TableUI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/TableUI.html) would be the class that could define the look and feel. Check out the [look and feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html) in java tutorials.